# Várias Requisições Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

Acabei de fazer uma rotina para resgatar informações do Google Maps, usando sua API. Mas eu precisei usar o CURL no PHP para fazer a requisição, porquê quando faço direto em AJAX no JS, me acusa o erro de Allow Origins Access Control e eu nunca consegui resolver isso.

Então parti para o CURL. Mas independente disso acontece que são várias requisições. Eu estou pegando a distância de um endereço para o outro pela API do Google.

E são várias registros em tela e preciso da distância de cada um em tempo real, visto que eu pego a localização atual do usuário.

Então podem ser mais de 10 requisições.

Existe alguma forma melhor de se fazer isso ?

Para entenderem vou postar o código:

```
$.each(allEnderecos, function(i, v){
    var enderecoLocal = $(v).val();
    $.ajax({
        url: urlBase + '/select-endereco-local',
        data: { ea: enderecoAtual, el: enderecoLocal },
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        success: function(data){
            $(v).closest('div.info-dealer').find('span.geoval').html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Vejam o `each`. É uma quantidade desconhecida de endereços que podem ter em tela. Depende da consulta do usuário.

1 - Isso é perigoso ?

2 - Interfere na performance  do site ?

Pensei sem levar as informações tudo de uma vez e retornar tudo de uma vez. Mas no PHP tem um CURL pra outro LINK, então acho que dá no mesmo.

Comment: Você vai fazer elas em paralelo ? precisa de uma forma genérica de fazer?

Comment: Não, é em série. Como no código acima. Uma atrás da outra.

Comment: uma depende da outra, hm, você sabe que o metodo async false do ajax esta depreciado né? você pode utilizar o metodo .success ou .done para executar dps que terminar a requisição, da uma olhada nesse exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/gabrielr47/3da9aswq/4/

Comment: Sei sim. Mas uma não depende da outra. São requisições diferentes. Veja o código que postei. É um `for`. Ele busca uma informação e retorna num `span`, depois outra, depois outra... diferentes...

Comment: @Zoom, se o servidor suportar a concorencia, não vejo problemas na sua abordagem. caso venha a ter um problema de desempenho devido a concorrencia, você pode tentar implementar uma pool para as suas requisições AJAX no cliente. uma alternativa seria fazer o seu método possuir um retorno asyncrono, algo trivial usando `ASP.NET WebAPI`, `NodeJS/ExpressJS` ou `SparkJava`, mas infelizmente o `PHP` ainda não dá suporte a `async/await`, apesar de já ter reservado esta palavras. Mas se este método vier a se tornar um gargalo, por ser um metodo simples, talvez vala a pena faze-lo em outra tecnologia.

Comment: @Zoom, uma outra opção para requisições asyncronas seria migrar parte do seu codigo de `PHP` para [`Hack`](http://hacklang.org), lembrando que este ultimo é bem semelhante ao `PHP` e é compartivel com o mesmo, porém dá suporte à `async`.